# Parsing csv file and skip the first 3000 lines

Tags: algorithm, perl, parsing, csv

I did this function to modify my csv file :

```
    sub convert
{
    # open the output/input file 
my $file = $firstname."_lastname_".$age.".csv";
 $file =~ /(.+\/)(.+\.csv)/;
my $file_simple = $2;
open my $in, '<', $file or die "can not read the file: $file $!";
open my $out, '>', $outPut."_lastname.csv" or die "can not open the o file:  $!";

$_ = <$in>;

# first line
print $out "X,Y,Z,W\n";
while( <$in> )
{
    if(/(-?\d+),(-?\d+),(-?\d+),(-?\d+),(-?\d+)/)
    {
        my $tmp = ($4.$5);
        print $out $2.$sep.$3.$sep.$4.$sep.($5/10)."\n";
    }
    else
    {print $out "Error: ".$_;}
}
close $out;
}
```

I would like to skip the first 3000 lines and i have no idea to do it,it's my first time using perl.

Thank you.

Comment: Add a counter and call next if the counter < 3000

Comment: @Jens; i get this error Bareword "co" not allowed while "strict subs"

Comment: in which line you get the error? There is missing a my declaration for a variable co.

Comment: @Jens;it's ok ,it was my fault ,i didn't understand your answer,thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wish to **to skip the first 3000 lines**, just use `next if` in tandem with the [current line number variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) `$.`:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $skip_lines = 3001;

open(my $fh, '<', 'data.dat') or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    next if $. < $skip_lines;
    //process the file
}
close($fh);
```

**Since `$.` checks the current line number, this program simply tells perl to start at the 3001st line, effectively skipping 3000 lines. As desired.**

> $. Current line number for the last filehandle accessed. Each
>   filehandle in Perl counts the number of lines that have been read from
>   it. (Depending on the value of $/ , Perl's idea of what constitutes a
>   line may not match yours.) When a line is read from a filehandle (via
>   readline() or <> ), or when tell() or seek() is called on it, $.
>   becomes an alias to the line counter for that filehandle. You can
>   adjust the counter by assigning to $. , but this will not actually
>   move the seek pointer. Localizing $. will not localize the
>   filehandle's line count. Instead, it will localize perl's notion of
>   which filehandle $. is currently aliased to. $. is reset when the
>   filehandle is closed, but not when an open filehandle is reopened
>   without an intervening close(). For more details, see I/O Operators in
>   perlop. Because <> never does an explicit close, line numbers increase
>   across ARGV files (but see examples in eof). You can also use
>   HANDLE->input_line_number(EXPR) to access the line counter for a given
>   filehandle without having to worry about which handle you last
>   accessed. Mnemonic: many programs use "." to mean the current line
>   number.

REFERENCE:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: Thank's,first time using next if :)